# aligning element of matrix spacing multiline

Tags: matrices

Since this matrix is ​​so long, it can only fit in 3 rows, but its elements are not aligned one under the other. How can I align this? Because it's not visually good this way

```tex
\begin{multline*}
\left[\begin{matrix}  \begin{array}{ccc}
                      \langle(0.70,0.80,0.90,1.00);0.7,0.8,0.9,0.2\rangle\\ \langle(0.50,0.60,0.70,0.80);0.1,0.7,0.8,0.9\rangle\\ \langle(0.70,0.80,0.90,1.00);0.7,0.8,0.9,0.2\rangle \\ \langle(0.50,0.60,0.70,0.80);0.1,0.7,0.8,0.9\rangle\\ \langle(0.01,0.05,0.10,0.15);0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4\rangle \\\langle(0.10,0.20,0.20,0.30);0.3,0.4,0.8,0.1\rangle\\
                      \end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}
                      \langle(0.15,0.20,0.25,0.30);0.4,0.6,0.2,0.5\rangle\\ \langle(0.25,0.30,0.35,0.40);0.4,0.5,0.6,0.8\rangle\\ \langle(0.01,0.05,0.10,0.15);0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4\rangle \\ \langle(0.40,0.45,0.50,0.55);0.8,0.9,0.3,0.6\rangle\\ \langle(0.45,0.55,0.65,0.75);0.7,0.8,0.6,0.3\rangle \\\langle(0.15,0.20,0.25,0.30);0.4,0.6,0.2,0.5\rangle\\
                      \end{array}\end{matrix}\right. \\
                      \left.\begin{matrix}\begin{array}{ccc}
                      \langle(0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20);0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1\rangle\\ \langle(0.40,0.45,0.50,0.55);0.8,0.9,0.3,0.6\rangle\\ \langle(0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20);0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1\rangle \\ \langle(0.25,0.30,0.35,0.40);0.4,0.5,0.6,0.8\rangle\\ \langle(0.01,0.05,0.10,0.15);0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4\rangle \\\langle(0.70,0.80,0.90,1.00);0.7,0.8,0.9,0.2\rangle\\
                      \end{array}  & \begin{array}{ccc}
                      \langle(0.10,0.20,0.20,0.30);0.3,0.4,0.8,0.1\rangle\\ \langle(0.50,0.60,0.70,0.80);0.1,0.7,0.8,0.9\rangle\\ \langle(0.10,0.20,0.20,0.30);0.3,0.4,0.8,0.1\rangle \\ \langle(0.10,0.20,0.20,0.30);0.3,0.4,0.8,0.1\rangle\\ \langle(0.45,0.55,0.65,0.75);0.7,0.8,0.6,0.3\rangle \\\langle(0.25,0.30,0.35,0.40);0.4,0.5,0.6,0.8\rangle\\
                      \end{array}\end{matrix}\right. \\
        \left.\begin{matrix} \begin{array}{ccc}
                      \langle(0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20);0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1\rangle\\ \langle(0.10,0.15,0.15,0.20);0.2,0.4,0.5,0.3\rangle\\ \langle(0.30,0.35,0.40,0.45);0.6,0.1,0.8,0.4\rangle \\ \langle(0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20);0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1\rangle\\ \langle(0.15,0.20,0.25,0.30);0.4,0.6,0.2,0.5\rangle \\\langle(0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20);0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1\rangle\\
                      \end{array} &\begin{array}{ccc}
                      \langle(0.40,0.45,0.50,0.55);0.8,0.9,0.3,0.6\rangle\\ \langle(0.01,0.05,0.10,0.15);0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4\rangle\\ \langle(0.70,0.80,0.90,1.00);0.7,0.8,0.9,0.2\rangle \\ \langle(0.70,0.80,0.90,1.00);0.7,0.8,0.9,0.2\rangle\\ \langle(0.45,0.55,0.65,0.75);0.7,0.8,0.6,0.3\rangle \\\langle(0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20);0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1\rangle\\
                      \end{array} \end{matrix}\right. \\
       \left.\begin{matrix}  \begin{array}{ccc}
                      \langle(0.25,0.30,0.35,0.40);0.4,0.5,0.6,0.8\rangle\\ \langle(0.30,0.35,0.40,0.45);0.6,0.1,0.8,0.4\rangle\\ \langle(0.45,0.55,0.65,0.75);0.7,0.8,0.6,0.3\rangle \\ \langle(0.30,0.35,0.40,0.45);0.6,0.1,0.8,0.4\rangle\\ \langle(0.01,0.05,0.10,0.15);0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4\rangle \\\langle(0.30,0.35,0.40,0.45);0.6,0.1,0.8,0.4\rangle\\
 \end{array}\end{matrix}\right]
\end{multline*}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `align` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\left[
  \begin{matrix}
  \langle(0.70,0.80,0.90,1.00);0.7,0.8,0.9,0.2\rangle \\
  \langle(0.50,0.60,0.70,0.80);0.1,0.7,0.8,0.9\rangle \\
  \langle(0.70,0.80,0.90,1.00);0.7,0.8,0.9,0.2\rangle \\
  \langle(0.50,0.60,0.70,0.80);0.1,0.7,0.8,0.9\rangle \\
  \langle(0.01,0.05,0.10,0.15);0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4\rangle \\
  \langle(0.10,0.20,0.20,0.30);0.3,0.4,0.8,0.1\rangle \\
  \end{matrix}
\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
&\quad
  \begin{matrix}
  \langle(0.15,0.20,0.25,0.30);0.4,0.6,0.2,0.5\rangle \\
  \langle(0.25,0.30,0.35,0.40);0.4,0.5,0.6,0.8\rangle \\
  \langle(0.01,0.05,0.10,0.15);0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4\rangle \\
  \langle(0.40,0.45,0.50,0.55);0.8,0.9,0.3,0.6\rangle \\
  \langle(0.45,0.55,0.65,0.75);0.7,0.8,0.6,0.3\rangle \\
  \langle(0.15,0.20,0.25,0.30);0.4,0.6,0.2,0.5\rangle \\
  \end{matrix}
\\
  \begin{matrix}
  \langle(0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20);0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1\rangle \\
  \langle(0.40,0.45,0.50,0.55);0.8,0.9,0.3,0.6\rangle \\
  \langle(0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20);0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1\rangle \\
  \langle(0.25,0.30,0.35,0.40);0.4,0.5,0.6,0.8\rangle \\
  \langle(0.01,0.05,0.10,0.15);0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4\rangle \\
  \langle(0.70,0.80,0.90,1.00);0.7,0.8,0.9,0.2\rangle \\
  \end{matrix}
&\quad
  \begin{matrix}
  \langle(0.10,0.20,0.20,0.30);0.3,0.4,0.8,0.1\rangle \\
  \langle(0.50,0.60,0.70,0.80);0.1,0.7,0.8,0.9\rangle \\
  \langle(0.10,0.20,0.20,0.30);0.3,0.4,0.8,0.1\rangle \\
  \langle(0.10,0.20,0.20,0.30);0.3,0.4,0.8,0.1\rangle \\
  \langle(0.45,0.55,0.65,0.75);0.7,0.8,0.6,0.3\rangle \\
  \langle(0.25,0.30,0.35,0.40);0.4,0.5,0.6,0.8\rangle \\
  \end{matrix}
\\
  \begin{matrix}
  \langle(0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20);0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1\rangle \\
  \langle(0.10,0.15,0.15,0.20);0.2,0.4,0.5,0.3\rangle \\
  \langle(0.30,0.35,0.40,0.45);0.6,0.1,0.8,0.4\rangle \\
  \langle(0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20);0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1\rangle \\
  \langle(0.15,0.20,0.25,0.30);0.4,0.6,0.2,0.5\rangle \\
  \langle(0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20);0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1\rangle \\
  \end{matrix}
&\quad
  \begin{matrix}
  \langle(0.40,0.45,0.50,0.55);0.8,0.9,0.3,0.6\rangle \\
  \langle(0.01,0.05,0.10,0.15);0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4\rangle \\
  \langle(0.70,0.80,0.90,1.00);0.7,0.8,0.9,0.2\rangle \\
  \langle(0.70,0.80,0.90,1.00);0.7,0.8,0.9,0.2\rangle \\
  \langle(0.45,0.55,0.65,0.75);0.7,0.8,0.6,0.3\rangle \\
  \langle(0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20);0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1\rangle \\
  \end{matrix}
\\
&\quad
\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
  \begin{matrix}
  \langle(0.25,0.30,0.35,0.40);0.4,0.5,0.6,0.8\rangle \\
  \langle(0.30,0.35,0.40,0.45);0.6,0.1,0.8,0.4\rangle \\
  \langle(0.45,0.55,0.65,0.75);0.7,0.8,0.6,0.3\rangle \\
  \langle(0.30,0.35,0.40,0.45);0.6,0.1,0.8,0.4\rangle \\
  \langle(0.01,0.05,0.10,0.15);0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4\rangle \\
  \langle(0.30,0.35,0.40,0.45);0.6,0.1,0.8,0.4\rangle \\
  \end{matrix}
\right]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]